# How to cancel group(bundle) notification when group has only one notification?

Tags: android, notifications

Below is the sample activity, has code to create bundle notifications and group.
When i click on last notification(when one is remaining) .Group notification does not disappear on consumption of last notification.
**strong text**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button btnBundleNotification, btnSingleNotification;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
int bundleNotificationId = 100;
int singleNotificationId = 100;
NotificationCompat.Builder summaryNotificationBuilder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    btnBundleNotification = findViewById(R.id.btnBundleNotification);
    btnSingleNotification = findViewById(R.id.btnSingleNotification);
    btnBundleNotification.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSingleNotification.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBundleNotification:


            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel groupChannel = new NotificationChannel("bundle_channel_id", "bundle_channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(groupChannel);
            }
            bundleNotificationId += 100;
            singleNotificationId = bundleNotificationId;
            String bundle_notification_id = "bundle_notification_" + bundleNotificationId;
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification", "Summary Notification Clicked");
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification_id", bundleNotificationId);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, bundleNotificationId, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            summaryNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "bundle_channel_id")
                    .setGroup(bundle_notification_id)
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Bundled Notification. " + bundleNotificationId)
                    .setContentText("Content Text for bundle notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(bundleNotificationId, summaryNotificationBuilder.build());

            break;

        case R.id.btnSingleNotification:


            bundle_notification_id = "bundle_notification_" + bundleNotificationId;

            resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification", "Summary Notification Clicked");
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification_id", bundleNotificationId);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, bundleNotificationId, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            //We need to update the bundle notification every time a new notification comes up.
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannels().size() < 2) {
                    NotificationChannel groupChannel = new NotificationChannel("bundle_channel_id", "bundle_channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(groupChannel);
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
            }
            summaryNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "bundle_channel_id")
                    .setGroup(bundle_notification_id)
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Bundled Notification " + bundleNotificationId)
                    .setContentText("Content Text for group summary")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


            if (singleNotificationId == bundleNotificationId)
                singleNotificationId = bundleNotificationId + 1;
            else
                singleNotificationId++;

            resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification", "Single notification clicked");
            resultIntent.putExtra("notification_id", singleNotificationId);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, singleNotificationId, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                    .setGroup(bundle_notification_id)
                    .setContentTitle("New Notification " + singleNotificationId)
                    .setContentText("Content for the notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setGroupSummary(false)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(singleNotificationId, notification.build());
            notificationManager.notify(bundleNotificationId, summaryNotificationBuilder.build());
            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int notification_id = extras.getInt("notification_id");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification with ID " + notification_id + " is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You may find this link ( https://blog.danlew.net/2017/02/07/correctly-handling-bundled-android-notifications/ ) useful. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Summary notification **will not automatically get cleared** when the last notification of that group is consumed. You must clear the summary notification manually yourself.

That means you must keep track of all notifications your apps have created.

```
private int countForNotificationsInGroup = 0 ;
```

Increment that value each time you create a new notification of under that summary notification.

Then decrement notification count when each notification is consumed. When the count reaches zero, clear the summary notification.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int notification_id = extras.getInt("notification_id");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification with ID " + notification_id + " is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);

        countForNotificationsInGroup = countForNotificationsInGroup - 1;

        if(countForNotificationsInGroup==0)
        {
           //clear summary notification
           notificationManager.cancelAll();
        }
    }
}
```

You may like to read more about correctly handling bundled Android notifications [here](https://blog.danlew.net/2017/02/07/correctly-handling-bundled-android-notifications/).

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
.setAutoCancel(true)
```

in your summary  notification builder. It cancels the whole group summary notification only after the last child notification is clicked. Tested on API level 30.

Answer (score -2):

What I understood that you want to clear all the notifications from system tray.

You can add following in your onNewIntent() method

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nMgr.cancelAll();
```

Hopefully It works for you.